# SSH connection refused. Port closed is the status for port scanning

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, recovery

I have an ec2 instance that has been in use for a couple of years and it is being used for multiple purposes. But can't ssh into the instance as it says connection refused. I stopped the instance and detached the volume and attached it onto a new instance to check ssh config and in fact I had replaced the current config with default and also added a line called `UseDNS no`. I had no luck.

I tried to run a script using user data for aws which am sure didn't work. I mounted the volume of the server on to a new server and wrote a BASH script to start netcat, make sure ssh service is running and firewall ports are open and added a command in `/etc/rc.local` to give executable permissions to run the script. I'm not sure if the startup script is running or is there any other suggestions on how to fix this issue?

The sshd_config looks like this:

```
Port 22
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin yes
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintLastLog yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox      # Default for new installations.
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY    LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
UseDNS no
```

The ssh_config is the same as Default.

SSH verbose output:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "x.x.x.x" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
```

Nmap results:

```
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp    closed ssh
80/tcp    open   http
110/tcp   open   pop3
143/tcp   open   imap
443/tcp   closed https
993/tcp   open   imaps
995/tcp   open   pop3s
8080/tcp  closed http-proxy
```

The server has the aws credentials configured. BASH script I'm running is looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install ssh netcat -y
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo service ssh stop
sudo service ssh start
sudo touch /home/ubuntu/logs
sudo service --status-all >> /home/ubuntu/logs
sudo aws s3 cp /home/ubuntu/logs s3://recover-server
sudo nc -l 9999 &
```

I can't connect to the server over SSH as it still says connection refused, I tried using the pem key and also I added my public key to the authorized_hosts file. I'm also not able to connect the netcat reverse shell. I have whitelisted my IP address in the Security Group. On port scanning using NMAP it says port 22 closed. Any suggestions on how to approach this issue and recover the server?

Comment: Does the security group still allow port 22 access?

Comment: Yes! The security group allows port 22 access to my home IP.

Comment: Can you take an AMI of the server & try to SSH (Use same key & Security group)?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it and it has the same issues.